# Authorization spec not working for put request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

Im on chp 9 of Michael Hartls Ruby On Rails Tutorial. In my **authentication_pages_specs.rb** the 'submitting to the update action' is causing the spec to crash with the error **"undefined local variable or method `user' for # (NameError)"**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do
  subject { page }


  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "in the users controller" do
        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user)}
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in')}
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          describe { put user_path(user)}  #Error on this line
          specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Whats cauing the spec to  crash ?

Thank You

Comment: For starters, just looking at it, you have `{put user_path(user)}` in a `describe` block, it should be in a `it` block.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out ! :). Its should be in a before block instead of it however.

Answer (score 0):

Putting in before block the put part fixes the problem